# Any fix for audio stuttering (incoming and outgoing) when making Skype calls?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-hero, skype

I have an HTC hero with Android 2.1, and the latest Skype available in android marketplace (december 2010) stutters badly on wifi.

(I did not even try to make a skype call over 3g data, i think that would be silly, and in my market where data charges are exorbitant, a waste of money.)

I believe it's a performance problem with my phone.  I have tried to uninstall some other apps, and not very much seems to be open and running on my phone (just skype, the phone main UI panel).

Audio coming to my headphones stutters terribly and is full of clicks.  The audio going out is reported to be bad when I tested it with human callers, but when I used the echo123 skype service, my audio came back to me mostly perfectly.

It looks like Skype's website lists the following as compatible android handsets:
"Android devices: DROID by Motorola, DROID ERIS by HTC, Motorola DEVOUR™, HTC Droid Incredible, LG Ally, Samsung Fascinate™, Motorola Droid X, Motorola Droid 2, Samsung CONTINUUM, Motorola Ciena, Motorola Droid 2 Global."

[Note that HTC hero is not in that list]

Comment: not unique to HTC Hero, I think, I had this as well on Spica. Incidentally, it also turned my phone into a pocket warmer.

Comment: P Were you on wifi or using 3G?

Comment: I was using wifi.  3g would be so slow I wouldn't be surprised if the audio stuttered. Plus who pays data rates (3g) for voice on Skype?  Silly...

Comment: @Warren: That actually makes sense when you have a flat rate 3G subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the HTC Hero doesn't have enough CPU to handle the audio codecs.

You may have some success rooting it and overclocking the CPU, but it'll shorten the life of your hardware and void your warranty.

Comment: I also have come to this conclusion.  600 mhz, or whatever the Hero is, isn't 1 ghz, which is the what the newer handsets run at.  Whatever profiling and testing the developers of Skype for Android did, the Hero's cpu wasn't their acceptance test criteria, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

This would be related to your data network speed rather than the application. Try to test it with a wifi connection and see if that gets you better audio.

Comment: I was using WIFI not the data network.  I wouldn't dare try it with the data network.  My guess is that the CPU in my Hero isn't up to running skype.

Comment: Okay that is strange. I guess you checked signal strength?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a carrier problem.  When the Amazon Mp3 app recently updated it had a warning message to contact Sprint if there was any stuttering with the music since Sprint's network doesn't work well with streaming audio.  I haven't had an issue yet so I removed the notice otherwise I'd post it here for you to see.  It's only a guess though so since I'm basing this completely on what I read in that notice from Amazon.

Comment: No, because I was using Wifi.